# Last element i a django foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling getting the right query for my project. How can i get the last lesson in a specific module . I intended to show a message to a user when he completes the last lesson of a module i.e "Congrats use you have completed module blah blah blah" this message needs only to be flashed once the last lesson of a module has been completed.

```
class Module(models.Model):
    DRAFT = 1
    SUSPENDED = 2
    PUBLISHED = 3
    MODULE_STATUSES = (
        (DRAFT, _("Draft")),
        (SUSPENDED, _("Suspended")),
        (PUBLISHED, _("Published"))
    )
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Module Name"), max_length=200, help_text=_('The module title'))
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Module Description", help_text=_("Module description"))
    prerequisite = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name=_("Prerequisite Module"), null=True, blank=True, default=None)   
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, help_text=_('Unique identifier'))
    status = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Module Status", choices=MODULE_STATUSES, default=PUBLISHED)
    position = PositionField(collection='course', default=0)
    end_of_module = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Module Summary"), default=None, null=True, help_text=_("Wrap and summarize this module"))
    last_module = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name=_("Previous Module"), null=True, blank=True, default=None, related_name="previous_module")
    next_module = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name=_("Next Module"), null=True, blank=True, default=None, related_name="the_next_module")


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Modules"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('module_detail', args=[self.slug])


class Lesson(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Lesson Title"), max_length=200, help_text=_('The lesson title'))
    prerequisite = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name=_("Prerequisite Lesson"), null=True, blank=True, default=None)   
    content = models.TextField()
    instructions_before = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Instructions before exercise"), null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    instructions_after = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Instructions after exercise"), null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    quizzes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz, verbose_name=_("Quiz"), blank=True, related_name='lessons')
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, help_text=_('Unique identifier'))
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise, verbose_name=_("Exercise"), blank=True, related_name='lesson_exercises')
    position = PositionField(collection='module', default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Lesson")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Lessons")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#filter) all the `Lessons` by `Lesson.module`. Then, [order by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) `Lesson.position` (reverse).